# Azure - how do I Docker exec into container with a Container Registry?

Tags: azure, docker

I want to `docker exec` into an Azure-hosted container.

However there seems to be several ways of hosting containers within Azure, and most of the guides and info I've found seem to be referencing a different way to how we've got it set up.

Our container is running as the result of the image being added as a "repo" within a "[container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/)". Separately from this, there are also things in Azure called container groups and container instances, neither of which, as I understand it, relate my setup.

So how can I exec into a container hosted in this way?

Here's what I've tried, as described by [this MS guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec), but again, this seems to assume the container groups/container instances approach, not my setup.

```
az container exec --resource-group unitsnew --name unitsreg --exec-command "whatever"
```

`unitsnew` is the name of my resource group, and `unitsreg` is my repo name within the container registry (I've also tried passing the name of the registry itself for this arg.)

Accordingly, this doesn't work; I'm told that:

> (ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/unitsreg.' under resource group 'unitsnew' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
> Code: ResourceNotFound
> Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/unitsreg' under resource group 'unitsnew' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix

[ --- EDIT --- ]

Setup info.

An appslot has its "source" (under Deployment Centre > Settings) set to "Container Registry".

The registry settings are then:

- Container type = single container
- Registry source = ACR
- Registry =
- Image =
- Tag = 'latest' (as stipulated in the Pipelines YAML)
- Startup file: `bin/rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0`

This, as I say, is linked to a Devops Pipeline that has the following YAML:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
  - my-gh-branch

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  imageRepository: 'panstudiohellolamppostapi_web'
  containerRegistry: '<redacted>.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: 'latest'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build and push stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - task: DockerCompose@0
            inputs:
              containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
              azureSubscription: 'Microsoft Azure Sponsorship(<redacted>)'
              azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"<redacted>.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/<redacted>"}'
              dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
              action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
              dockerComposeCommand: 'build'
          - task: DockerCompose@0
            inputs:
              containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
              azureSubscription: 'Microsoft Azure Sponsorship(<redacted>)'
              azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"<redacted>.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/<redacted>"}'
              dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
              action: 'Push services'
```

Comment: container registry is there to store images, there is no container running you could exec into.

Comment: Not true. My container is running and I can call up my app that's running inside it. Further, there are container logs which show what the container did, started the server inside it, listening to ports, etc etc.

Comment: then you are not talking about a container registry. Maybe you are confusing some terminoligy here. As it stands the registry (ACR) doesnt run images. It is like dockerhub or quay.io.

Comment: where do you see the logs?

Comment: I am definitely talking about a container registry. I will edit the question to provide more info.

Comment: Edits provided. Thanks for your help. I see the container logs within Kudu. I can see Docker starting up, running commands, starting the server, etc.

Comment: so your container runs in an app service. The app service pulls the image from the registry. The registry is the place to store the image, not to run it. App service is the place to run a container from your image. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-best-practices#continuously-deploy-containers

Comment: Thank you, that helps me understand what the hell is going on. However I'm still unsure how to CLI into my container. Everything I read on MS docs seems to assume that the container would be running as a container instance, not as an app service, and accordingly provides docs for that approach only.

Comment: I think you cannot do that with app service. You need to use container instances for this, which is another way to run container in azure.

Comment: Oh god. Right. So my app is throwing errors, and I can't get inside the container to look at the logs. I guess I could configure the app to throw logs to STDOUT so they show up in Container Logs or something. Dang...

Comment: Thats something you should do anyway. Container should log to stdout and not into the file system. The vast majority of tools around container build upon the assumption that this is the case. If its not feasable you could mount a volume to the place where your cointainer writes the log files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux&tabs=portal#link-storage-to-your-app

Answer (score 0):

As I understand,the error massage makes scene. az is looking for a running container of a container group.

as you can see be the help message az provides:

---

```
 az container exec
 the following arguments are required: --exec-command

 Examples from AI knowledge base:
 az container exec --exec-command "/bin/bash" --name mynginx --resource-group MyResourceGroup
 Execute a command from within a running container of a container group. (autogenerated)

 az container exec --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name mynginx --container-name nginx --exec-command "/bin/bash"
 Stream a shell from within an nginx container.

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/container#az_container_exec
 Read more about the command in reference docs


 az container exec --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name mynginx --container-name nginx --exec-command "/bin/bash"
 Stream a shell from within an nginx container.

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/container#az_container_exec
 Read more about the command in reference docs
```

---

You, as I understand, have only pushed your images to azure ACR. Pushing images to an Azure ACR isn't enough for a container to be running, Azure ACR functions like Dockerhub, it stores your artifacts, like docker images. if you want your images to run you can use container groups https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-groups.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, my container is *definitely* running. I can call up the app that's running inside it and see it for myself. Further, I have container logs showing container activity.